# solve least square problem with Multiple SDP constraints

Tags: optimization, least-squares

I have the following problem

$$min_{S,K,m} \quad ||Ax-b||^2 s.t \quad S \geq 0 , Z \geq 0$$

where, $x= \begin{pmatrix}  S \\ m\\ K \end{pmatrix},$
$$S:= \begin{bmatrix}
   s_{1}      & s_{2} &  \\
    s_{3}      & s_{4}  \\
    \end{bmatrix} \geq 0,
$$ S is 2 by 2 matrix
and
$$Z:= \begin{bmatrix}
   K   & m &  \\
    m^T      & 1  \\
    \end{bmatrix} \geq 0 ,
$$
Z is 3 by 3 matrix
where,
$ K := \begin{bmatrix}
    m_{1}^2   &  m_{2}m_{1}  &  \\
    m_{1}m_{2}      & m_{2}^2  \\
    \end{bmatrix} \geq 0 $

$m= \begin{pmatrix}  m_{1}  \\m_{2} \end{pmatrix},$

My first question: How can I solve this problem ? especially I have two SDP constraints ?
I read about something called block diagonal matrix. What I understand is to convert the two constraints into one constraints, my new problem will be  as follow :

$min  ||Ax-b||^2 $
s.t

$L:= \begin{bmatrix}
   matrix S   & 0 &  \\
   0      & matrix Z  \\
    \end{bmatrix} \geq 0
$
is this is correct ? how can I assure the off diagonal elements are zero? should I add constraints for that

Second question: I want to code this problem which solver can help me with that ?

Comment: Your question should be better exposed. You have not defined many of the notations you are considering. Please also clarify which variables are data of the problem and which ones are decision variables. As stated there is no correlation between $S$, $Z$ and the cost to minimize.

Comment: I edited the question with more details provided

Comment: You have not clarified the relationship between the cost of the constraints. As stated there is no decision variables in the cost function.

Comment: x is matrix of decision variables , $x=\begin{pmatrix} S \\ m \\ K \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: If $K$ or $S$ are matrices, then the vector $x$ as you defined does not make much sense. Perhaps, you can use the vectorization operators if you want to write $x$ like that. If $S$ is symmetric, this is an SDP that can be used using any standard SDP solver such as SeDuMi, SDPT-3, MOSEK, etc. You have Matlab and Python interfaces for them. With Matlab, you can use the parsers Yalmip or CVX to write your SDP problem and call the solver.

Comment: K is 2 by 2 matrix and S is 2 by 2 matrix ,  S is symmetric , please check my last update

Comment: $||Ax-b||$ means [Frobenius norm or Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)? It is not clear how are you doing the multiplication $Ax$, and hence what is $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to try to implement a semidefinite relaxation of a problem involving a quartic objective, and a semidefinite constraint on some variables.

The idea in a semidefinite relaxation is that you replace the quadratic terms $mm^T$ with linear elements from a matrix $M$, and then add the constraint that $M$ has rank 1. As you have written it now, keeping the outer product (which trivially is positive semidefinite) and the nonlinear terms does not make any sense.

The model you probably look for, implemented using YALMIP, would be

```
S = sdpvar(2,2);
m = sdpvar(2,1);
K = sdpvar(2);
x = [S(:);m(:);K(:)]; 
Objective = (A*x-b)'*(A*x-b);
Constraints = [S>=0, [K m;m' 1] >= 0] % Relaxation as rank constraint dropped
optimize(Constraints,Objective)
```

More generally, you are doing this
https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/momentrelaxations/

Comment: thank you, by introducing a variable e,g, $N=  mm^T$   and implement a semidefinite relaxation : we replace :  $N=  mm^T \Rightarrow N \geq  mm^T$  meaning $N-mm^T \geq 0 $? how can we prove this is true?

Comment: If $N = mm^T$ you know $N\geq 0$ and rank 1, hence you replace $N = mm^T$ with $N \geq mm^T$  and $N$ rank 1, and then drop the rank constraint and obtain a convex relaxation, and apply a Schur complement to arrive at a linear SDP.

Comment: You mean I can say: the condition $N=mm^T$ is equivalent to $ N \succeq 0 $ and Rank(N) = 1 ( these tow conditions equivariant because , when we relax the condition  $N=mm^T$ by $N \geq mm^T$ and Rank(N) = 1 . $N \geq mm^T$ means $N- mm^T\geq 0$ then we use  Schur complement  to convert $N- mm^T\geq 0$ to $ \begin{bmatrix}
   N      & m &  \\
    m^T      & 1  \\
    \end{bmatrix} \geq 0
$  
and drop the rank-one constraint to obtain SDP.

Comment: That is the basic idea in semidefinite relaxations, yes.

Comment: about the code I am looking for the value of x , so I write solution =value(x) , how ever I was expecting the solution for K variable to be $mm^T $  but I the results were different , should I add this to the constraint or define my K differently to assure the result matrix value related to $mm^T $

Comment: You have solved a relaxation, hence all you have done is that you've computed a lower bound on the achievable objective. There is no guarantee that $K=mm^T$. If that was the case, it would not be a relaxation and you would have solved the original problem.

Comment: Ok I got that,thank you, actually the case is to calculate the x variables ( root of the.equation). I wrote value(x) to calculate it , is this is correct ? another question, if I want to write down how I did estimate the root of the equation manually how can this be done ?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. If you want to solve the original quartic problem (and thus compute the globally optimal solution $(S,m)$) or if you want to compute a lower bound (possibly making it tight by using a higher order relaxation, through the introduction of the moments $K$ and generalizations).  If you need a solution, you either have to use a global solver instead and skip the whole use of $K$ etc, or use a higher-order relaxation and hope you obtain a tight relaxation from which a solution can be extracted.

Comment: I need to compute (S,m,K) values by  implement a semidefinite relaxation of a problem involving least square objective and another  semidefinite constraint on some variables.

Comment: Well then the answer is above, and you just have to understand that the computed $S$ and $m$ are not necessarily solutions to the problem (as you've solved a relaxation), and $K=mm^T$ does not necessarily hold either.

Comment: is there any way can help to make sure that I obtain a tight relaxation from which a solution can be extracted ?

Comment: what I meant precisely by my above question is how to know the solution quality of the relaxed  program?

Comment: If $K=mm^T$ then the problem has obviously been solved without any relaxation gap. If not, it could be that it is a lower bound only and you thus do not know. There is no magic way to guarantee a tight solution (except that in theory you can, under some regularity assumptions, have finite convergence to a tight solution by solving higher-order relaxations and hope they yield a tight solution before the problem gets too complex to be solved). If you must have a solution, why don't you simply try a global solver.

Comment: I applied the code you provided it and it gave me some results , but now I tried to rerun it and I am receiving an error : Undefined function or variable 'getavailablesolvers'.

Error in compileinterfacedata (line 164)
    [solvers,kept,allsolvers] = getavailablesolvers(findallsolvers,options);

Error in solvesdp (line 249)
[interfacedata,recoverdata,solver,diagnostic,F,Fremoved,ForiginalQuadratics] =
compileinterfacedata(F,[],logdetStruct,h,options,0,solving_parametric);

Error in optimize (line 31)
[varargout{1:nargout}] = solvesdp(varargin{:});  any idea about this error ?

Comment: YALMIP issues should be posted on YALMIP forums (google groups or github discussions)

Comment: how would I know about which algorithm has used in YALMIP to solve sdp problem as the above problem ? I could not find anything help me

Comment: YALMIP does not solve any SDP problem, but formulates the moment relaxation and calls an installed SDP solver https://yalmip.github.io/tags/#semidefinite-programming-solver

Comment: Thank you , but how would I specify which solver has been applied to the above code? I am very sorry  but I am new to the field and struggling a lot

Comment: To get it to work well, you should have installed a good SDP solver. If you haven't installed an SDP solver you are probably using Mathworks LMILab (which is pretty poor). Which solver that was used is written in the output from optimize.